# How do i implement autosuggest functionality along with remove button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to implement tag functionality just like in stackoverflow website that is the feature to remove tags also.

I am referring to jquery ui autocomplete plugin.

For remove functionality i am referring to following website: [website link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/)

The functionality i require is that the tag should be comma separated, there should be a limit on the no of tags a user can select & there should be the functionality for removing the tags also.

I know that there is provision in select function to restrict the no. of suggestions.

I tried to merge the functionality given on the mentioned websites.

For this i have modified the select function.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
                            var terms = split( this.value );
                            if (terms.length <= 2) {
                            // remove the current input
                            terms.pop();
                            // add the selected item
                            terms.push( ui.item.value );
                            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                            terms.push( "" );
                             var friend = ui.item.value,  
                span = $("<span>").text(friend),  
                a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({  
                    href: "javascript:",  
                    title: "Remove " + friend  
                }).text("x").appendTo(span);  

                //add friend to friend div  
                span.insertBefore("#txtTopic");  
                            } else {
                                terms.pop();
                            }                               
                            this.value = terms.join( "," );
                            return false;
                        }
```

Right now i am getting following result:

[image]

How do i implement this feature that is multiple tags with restrictions, comma separated and remove functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If its fine then you could use this plugin: [autosuggest plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin).